# Way to get end points of a time interval based on a date?

Tags: java, date

I think I can do this on my own but I don't want to reinvent a wheel (especially regarding date arithmetic) if I don't have to.

I'm making a swing application that has a drop down where a user can select a time interval with the options being `All, Today, This Week, This Month, This Quarter, This Year, Last Week, Last Month, Last Quarter, Last Year`.  When a user selects one of these I want to calculate the interval.

For instance, today is 1/19/2022.  If someone selected `This Week`, my `startDate` would be `2022-01-16 00:00:00` and my `endDate` would be `2022-01-22 11:59:59` (or perhaps it would make more sense to be `2022-01-23 00:00:00`?)

For the `All` Selection I've already implented a method where my `startDate` is January 1, 1970 and my `endDate` is a few years into the future from the current time.  I also was able to do `Today` by myself by just getting todays date and adjusting the times from midnight to midnight.

But for all these other options I don't know if there's already a library or such that has calculated them that I could leverage.  It's been a while since I touched java in general and don't know the ecosystem well.

Also important to this is that the endDate and startDates are either `java.util.Date` type or a sublclass of it as I need to integrate it with code that is counting on that.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I strongly recommend doing your date math with `java.time` types and converting to `java.util.Date` only when and if you have to.  For example, [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) is a great place to start.

Comment: Ah the temporal adjusters looks like just what I need - thanks!

Comment: Note that Sunday is not the first day of the week in every country in the world. I presume your _Swing_ application does not need to be internationalized, correct?

Comment: Correct, its a very small application with a small local user base.

Comment: Accounting for time zone is not really any extra work once you understand a few basic concepts. And keeping your code time zone savvy can save a world of hurt later.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `java.time.LocalDate`, which you can easily obtain from `java.util.Date` and convert back and forth if needed.

Here is how you can get the start of the current week using `LocalDate` (using the US locale, you can use something else if the start of the week is different)

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
TemporalField fieldUS = WeekFields.of(Locale.US).dayOfWeek();
System.out.println(now.with(fieldUS, 1));
```

You can find how to do the rest of your requirements from other StackOverflow posts with a little searching.

Here is how you can convert a `Date` to `LocalDate`

```
Date date = new Date();
LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

And convert from `LocalDate` to `Date`

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Answer (score 0):

## Time zone

You said:

> For instance, today is 1/19/2022. If someone selected This Week, my startDate would be 2022-01-16 00:00:00

Be aware that determining a moment requires a time zone. The time 00:00 on the 16th happened several hours earlier in Tokyo Japan than in Toledo Ohio US.

Also, some dates in some time zones, the day does not begin at 00:00. Rather than assume, let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime todayStartTokyo = ZonedDateTime.now( zTokyo ).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( zTokyo ) ;
```

## Months

For a month, use [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
ZoneId zAuckland = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , 1 , 19 ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Determine date range.

```
LocalDate dateStart = yw.atDay( 1 ) ;
LocalDate dateEnd = yw.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

Determine moments.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = dateStart.atStartOfDay( zAuckland ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = dateEnd.atStartOfDay( zAuckland ) ;
```

## Quarters

If your definition of quarters agrees with that of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project for its [`org.threeten.extra.Quarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html) enum and [`org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class.

Again, the definition of week used in that class conforms with ISO 8601. If your definition differs, this class will not work for you. An ISO 8601 week **starts on Monday**, and runs through Sunday, with week # 1 of the year having the **first Thursday** of the calendar year, for a resulting 52 or 53 full-seven-day weeks per week-based-year.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , 1 , 19 ) ;
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.from( localDate ) ;
LocalDate yqStart = yq.atDay( 1 ) ;
LocalDate yqEnd = yq.plusQuarters( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Same range in moments:

```
ZoneId zTunis = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = yqStart.atStartOfDay( zTunis ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = yqEnd.atStartOfDay( zTunis ) ;
```

## Weeks

As with quarters, for working with weeks I suggest adding the *ThreeTen-Extra* library for its [`org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class. The built-in *java.time* do have some week features, but they are limited.

```
ZoneId zEdmonton = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
LocalDate todayEdmonton = LocalDate.now( zEdmonton ) ;
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( todayEdmonton ) ;
```

Or, just:

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.now( zEdmonton ) ;
```

To determine date range:

```
LocalDate weekStart = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
LocalDate weekEnd = yw.plusWeeks( 1 ).atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

To determine a range of moments, use same code seen above, calling `atStartOfDay`.